# Extending an extension's controller

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, overrides, extend

I am trying to extend an extensions controller so I can make changes without hacking about with the vendor's code.

The extension's controller which I can trying to extend is

/app/community/Rewardpoints/controllers/IndexController.php

and it looks like the following

```
class Rewardpoints_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
   public function quotationAction(){

   }
}
```

This is what I have so far

**1)** Enable the module by creating `/app/etc/modules/Namespace_ModuleName.xml`

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_ModuleName>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
             <depends>
              <Rewardpoints/>
             </depends>
        </Namespace_ModuleName>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**2)** Set up the config `/app/code/local/Namespace/ModuleName/etc/config.xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?> 
 <config>  
      <frontend>
    <routers>
        <rewardpoints>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Namespace_ModuleName before="Rewardpoints">Namespace_ModuleName</Namespace_ModuleName>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </rewardpoints>
    </routers>
</frontend>
</config>
```

**3)** Set up the new control- /`app/code/local/Namespace/ModuleName/controller.php`

```
   class Namespace_ModuleName_IndexController extends Rewardpoints_IndexController
   {
        public function quotationAction()
        {
            echo 'test';
            exit;
        }
    }
```

The error that I am getting though is Fatal error: Class 'Rewardpoints_IndexController' not found in /app/code/local/Namespace/ModuleName/controllers/IndexController.php on line 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should include the file containing the controller you want to extend, because they are not auto-loaded for controllers. Something like :

```
<?php
include_once 'Rewardpoints/controllers/IndexController.php';
class Namespace_ModuleName_IndexController extends Rewardpoints_IndexController
{
    public function quotationAction()
    {
        echo 'test';
        exit;
    }
}
```

Your original module doesn't have package name though ? It's not very standard.

Comment: Thanks that has worked. Yes I thought the same as I have never seen any extensions packaged like that before. The extension is http://www.j2t-design.net/j2t-points-rewards.html

Comment: I'm not sure how this works without a namespace. But The Magento Way of requiring a controller is actually `require_once Mage::getConfig()->getModuleDir('controllers', 'RewardPoints') . '/IndexController.php';`